# Php code to prevent download image

Tags: php

In my site we are doing image protecting section. Can I protect images in my site from others without download.That is i want to protect my image from downloading by others.Is it possible using php code

Comment: Once you send an image to client browser, it's not yours

Comment: It's hard to work out exactly what you mean here, but I'm guessing you want to be able to display images on your page without users being able to save them to there computer, in which case the answer is "no". You can make it more difficult for the user to save the images using e.g. flash, but even then it is fairly easy to get around.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The answer is "no", but the question is valid.

Comment: Though there exist many solutions making this process painful for commn users (invisible div over the images, reload query blocking, and others I don't know).

Comment: @bdares Agreed it is a little harsh, but the OP has not provided any kind of information about [what they have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), and the question is built in a way that is dangerously close to "plz give me teh codez" and I'm fairly sure there will be many, many duplicates if you look for them

Comment: If you don't want people stealing your images, don't upload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using those images users to display you can not protect that.But if you are not using you can protect using the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't protect your images with PHP because PHP is server side. JS can be used because it's client side, but somebody can easily disable JS in their browser and save the image anyway. There is no way to fully protect the images that you're displaying. If it's available via the Internet, anyone can download it.

Answer (score 1):

If site visitors can see your images they will be able to save or make copies of them. E.g., they can do a screendump and save the image from the clipboard.

You can add a watermark to it.

You can write some copyright string on or near the image.